# Interact with command line client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to execute a number of command line programs I want to execute with a given set of parameters.

Problem is, that those command line programs ask for username and password at some point. According to their documentation it is not possible to pass those as additional parameters, but they have to be entered manually.

**How can I enter those parameters programmatically using node.js?**

So basically I want to ask the user *one time* for his/her credentials and then each time they are asked, enter them automatically.

I was able to read username and password from the command line, but I am not able to pass those on to other programs.

This is my current approach

```
// get username/password using readline

// execute next script
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec( 'someCommandClient -with Parameters', function( err , stdout, stderr ){

  // error handling
  if( err ){
   console.log( err );
   return
  }

  // XXX here we should react on being prompted for username and password
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [nexpect](https://github.com/nodejitsu/nexpect) (or a similar module which has a bash `expect`-like support)

Answer (score 0):

To make your code simpler, i recommend using the [readline-sync module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/readline-sync) when you want to query the user for data, instead of using the native one.

If you want to interact with a child process you can't use child_process.exec, but must use child_process.spawn instead (the former waits for the child process to quit to call your callback)

Then to pass username or password to the child process, you have to write to its stdin stream
http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin

Something like this should do the job

```
var child = require('child_process').spawn('someprocess');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
   if (data === 'Login: ')
      child.stdin.write('Sirko');
});
```